# Counting phrase frequencies in an html file

Tags: python, html, frequency, phrase

I'm currently trying to get used to Python and have recently hit block in my coding. I couldn't run a code that would count the number of times a phrase appears in an html file. I've recently received some help constructing the code for counting the frequency in a text file but am wondering there is a way to do this directly from the html file (to bypass the copy and paste alternative). Any advice will be sincerely appreciated. The previous coding I have used is the following:

```
#!/bin/env python 3.3.2
import collections
import re

# Defining a function named "findWords".
def findWords(filepath):
  with open(filepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
      words = re.findall('\w+', line.lower())
      yield from words

phcnt = collections.Counter()

from itertools import tee
phrases = {'central bank', 'high inflation'}
fw1, fw2 = tee(findWords('02.2003.BenBernanke.txt'))   
next(fw2)
for w1,w2 in zip(fw1, fw2):
  phrase = ' '.join([w1, w2])
  if phrase in phrases:
    phcnt[phrase] += 1

print(phcnt)
```

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter`

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil: Unfortunately, that only gives me a way to count for words, not phrases

Answer (score 1):

You can use some_str.count(some_phrase) function

```
In [19]: txt = 'Text mining, also referred to as text data mining, Text mining,\
         also referred to as text data mining,'
In [20]: txt.lower().count('data mining')
Out[20]: 2
```

Comment: Hey man, the original code I posted works on text files but what I'm wondering is how to use it directly on an html file.

Answer (score 0):

What about just stripping the html tags before doing the analysis? [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) does this job quite well.

```
import html2text
content = html2text.html2text(infile.read())
```

would give you the text content (somehow formatted, but this is no problem in your approach I think). There are options to ignore images and links additionally, which you would use like

```
h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.ignore_images = True
h.ignore_links = True
content = h.handle(infile.read())
```